# Informix - How to get wait value of current connection lock mode using SQL

Tags: sql, locking, informix

How to get wait value of current connection lock mode using SQL. Is it stored anywhere in the system tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the session's lockmode, isolation level and other information from the sysmaster view `syssqlcurses`.

Example:

```
SELECT scs_isolationlevel, scs_lockmode
FROM sysmaster:syssqlcurses
WHERE scs_sessionid = dbinfo("sessionid");

scs_isolationlevel  COMMITTED READ
scs_lockmode        0
```

A value of 0 for scs_lockmode means not wait, a value of -1 means wait forever and a positive integer value is the wait time in seconds.